# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string- Not sure why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My date Format is "MMddyy" in sql .. When am trying to do as below it through me the date conversion error but am not sure what I need to do there?? 
Condition Failing: My WarrantReceivedDate should be less than startDate
and DateWarrantExecuted should be >= StartDate ?
Any Help? Thanks in Advance

```
declare @startDate VARCHAR(6) = '010119'
declare @endDate VARCHAR(6) = '013119'

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    WarrantIssuingAuthority varchar(100),
    CountType varchar(100), 
    CountRecords int    
)

insert into @MyTable (WarrantIssuingAuthority, CountType, CountRecords)
select WarrantIssuingAuthority, 'WARRANTS BEGINNING OF MONTH', count(*) 
from [PM].WarrantInformation 
where TypeOfWarrantIssued!='COM'  
and HowExecuted!='R' and HowExecuted!='U' 
and DeletedIndicator!='D' 
and DeletedIndicator!='P'

and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST((RIGHT(WarrantReceivedDate,2) + LEFT(WarrantReceivedDate,4)) AS DATE),112) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST((RIGHT(@startDate,2) + LEFT(@startDate,4)) AS DATE),112)  
and (DateWarrantExecuted='' or (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST((RIGHT(DateWarrantExecuted,2) + LEFT(DateWarrantExecuted,4)) AS DATE),112) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST((RIGHT(@startDate,2) + LEFT(@startDate,4)) AS DATE),112)))

group by WarrantIssuingAuthority 

select * from @MyTable order by WarrantIssuingAuthority
```

Comment: why aren't you just using a datetime variable?

Comment: What line fails?  Try taking out one of your where clauses and try it and vice versa to find the one that breaks.  Also can try just selecting the code that you are doing the convert on to make sure you dont have bad data

Comment: Not enough information here to reproduce the issue and help you.

Comment: probably something on the `DateWarrantExecuted` or `WarrantReceivedDate` conversions but I agree with @TMcKeown that you should use a datetime variable instead of doing the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

We can't see the definition of your table or the data contained within but its possible that there is a value there that can't be properly converted to a date. For example, maybe there is a value `093118` which is a valid `varchar` value, but not a valid `date`.